# jQuery validation not waiting for remote rule

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am trying to use [jQuery validation remote method](http://jqueryvalidation.org/remote-method/) to check if a value is unique
The rule is added on submit to prevent it from being fired on every keystroke

```
var Id = $("#id").val();

$('#form').on('submit', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var newValue = $('#input').val();

$('#input').rules('add', {
    'remote': {
        url: '/MyController/CheckValue',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            id: Id,
            value: newValue
        }
    },
    messages: {
        'remote': 'This value is not valid'
    }
});

if ($('#form').valid()) {
    window.console.log('valid')
    // do something
}

$('#input').rules('remove', 'remote');
});
```

The action returns true or false after a call to a service

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult CheckValue(int? id, string value)
{
    bool available;
    using (var myServiceClient = new MyServiceClient())
    {
        available = myServiceClient.IsValueAvailable(id, value);
    }
    return this.Json(available);
}
```

The rule works fine, but the `$('#form').valid()` returns `true` everytime because it is not waiting for the remote rule to finish it's call.

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12981049/2409722) suggests to use `async: false` in the remote rule declaration but this freezes the browser.
The examples in the [documentation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/remote-method/) are not using this, so it should be working without it.

Is there something wrong with my validation rule ?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate) you should be attaching the rules and validation method directly to the form and using a `submitHandler` callback like so:

```
$('#form').validate({
    rules: {
        inputName: {
          remote: {
            url: '/MyController/CheckValue',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                id: Id,
                value: newValue
            }
        }
    },
    messages: {
        inputName: {
            remote: 'This value is not valid'
        }
    },
    submitHandler: function(form){
        // Do Stuff with Form
    }
}
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Close... the method is called `.validate()` not `.validation()`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I forgot to mention i was using jQuery validation combined with MVC unobtrusive validation, so this step is already done by this plugin, and the unobtrusive validation works fine.
I just want to add a new rule to the existing validation on the form, it works well with classic rules, but not with remote rules : the form is validated before the result of the remote validation.