# jQuery Stop validation on cancel ui dialog

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate, jquery-ui-dialog

I have several forms with separate validators defined. These all work fine and validates as expected. However if I click the cancel button in the dialog box it still validates the form and shows errors. I have to click the cancel button twice for the form to close. If I click the [x] to close the dialog I briefly see the error message but the form closes. I can live with that.

This is my code:

```js
var renewValidator = $("#FormRenew").validate({
  rules: {
    NewNo: {
      remote: {
        url: "action.php?checkDup=1"
      }
    }
  }
});

$("#dialog").dialog({
  bgiframe: true,
  autoOpen: false,
  width: 450,
  modal: true,
  buttons: {
    'Renew': function() {
      if (renewValidator.valid()) {
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "ajax.php",
          data: queryString,
          success: function(msg) {...
                                 }
                                 });
          $(this).dialog('close');
        }
               },
               Cancel: {
               text: 'Cancel',
               immediate: "true",
               formnovalidate: 'formnovalidate',
               class: 'cancel',
               click: function(e) {
          console.log('Cancel clicked!');
          e.preventDefault();
          $("form").validate().cancelSubmit = true;
          $(this).dialog('close');
        }
      }
    },
    beforeClose: function() {
      renewValidator.resetForm();
      $("#FormRenew").trigger("reset");
    }
  });
```

Initially I just had a simple cancel like this Cancel:

```js
function() {
    $(this).dialog('close');
}
```

But I added the various options as suggested in other posts. None works for me.

Comment: Create a working jsFiddle demo please.

Comment: Did you inspect your DOM to verify that `formnovalidate="formnovalidate"` is part of the cancel button's HTML markup?  This is all that matters.  If not, then you have a problem with jQuery UI.

Comment: Yes and it was :-(

Comment: @Sparky - Here is a jsFiddle demo showing the problem. [https://jsfiddle.net/3ob9dhxj/](https://jsfiddle.net/3ob9dhxj/)

Comment: The buttons are `type="button"` so there would be no need to try to block validation on click because it shouldn't be happening in the first place.  In other words, with `type="button"`, you **must** programmatically trigger the validation.  However, with your example, I cannot see where validation is being triggered.  It's the weirdest thing.

Comment: var renewValidator = $("#FormRenew").validate(...) sets up the validation. When the input looses focus by clicking the cancel button the validation is triggered. But why would I have to click cancel twice?  If you click the close button it closes straight away as expected.

Comment: Still do not have a fix.  However, the buttons have absolutely nothing to do with this.  [**Simply clicking anywhere on the page triggers validation!**](https://jsfiddle.net/g3cLhz2e/)  Now the mystery to solve is "why?", as I see no click handlers that would cause this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The buttons have absolutely nothing to do with this.  **Validation is triggered when you focus out of the field.**  Since the modal opens with the field in focus, simply clicking anywhere on the page causes a `focusout` event to fire and therefore triggers validation.

1. Setting the `onfocusout` option to `false` within `.validate()` is part of the solution.  However, as explained in my comments, you cannot trigger validation at all with any button because they are outside the `form` tags (and not `type="submit"`).
2. Change your `renewValidator.valid()` into `$("form").valid()` so validation can be programmatically triggered when `Renew` is clicked.

**IMPORTANT**:  Since your buttons are outside the `<form>`, you can also remove all that special "button canceling" code.  A button **cannot** submit or trigger validation when it's *outside* the `form` container or when it's `type="button"`.

**DEMO:  [jsfiddle.net/yggg588c/](https://jsfiddle.net/yggg588c/)**

Comment: unfortunately I've tried that already and although the minlength validition rule still works the remote does not. It triggers the call to the remote but even when that returns false it passes the $("form").valid() check :-(  I don't know how to mimic the ajax remote call on jsFiddle to show you

Comment: @Kirsten, that has nothing to do with the original question, which I solved.  Please post your troubles with `remote` as a new question. Thanks.

Comment: I have a remote in the question.  I think I have found a way to simulate the remote call.  It should returm false and my remote call returns false but on alerting the value it says true and the form is submitted. here is the updated jsFiddle [http://jsfiddle.net/yggg588c/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/yggg588c/1/)

Comment: @Kirsten, you mentioned absolutely nothing in the original question about `remote`.  The entire narrative was about the cancel button being broken, which I kindly solved for you after a great amount of effort.  Now if you have another question, please post a new question.  Otherwise, the original question about the broken cancel button has been fully explained and solved.

Comment: The problem seems to be that the valid check returns true before the check has completed.  I think I have found a solution. Adding async: true to the remote rule seems to do the trick.  I found the answer here [http://stackoverflow.com/a/12981049/7302483](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12981049/7302483)  Here is the updated jsFiddle [http://jsfiddle.net/yggg588c/2/](http://jsfiddle.net/yggg588c/2/)

Comment: Thanks for all your help. The problem now appears to be solved.