# jQuery valid() Gives Wrong Value in Delegated Blur Handler

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, asp.net-core

I am creating an ASP.NET Core web app, which uses [jQuery Validate](https://jqueryvalidation.org/) for client-side validation, and [jQuery Unobtrusive Validation](https://github.com/aspnet/jquery-validation-unobtrusive) to configure validation using HTML5 data-* attributes.  I have a text input, and I am handling its `blur` event via event delegation.  The code looks something like this:

```
$(document).ready(() => {
    $('#my-container').on('blur', '.my-input-class', (event) => {
        var isValid = $(event.target).valid();
        // Do stuff with isValid's boolean value
    });
});
```

Unfortunately, if I enter an invalid value in the input then tab out, then `isValid` is still set to `true`.  But if I click the input and click off again, then this second blur event correctly sets `isValid` to `false`.

I think somehow my blur handler is happening before the jQuery Validate blur handler, presumably because I'm using event delegation rather than directly handling `input.onblur()`.  Event delegation is necessary though because the input is generated dynamically, after [`validate()`](https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/) has already been called.  I've seen some posts suggest calling [`validator.element()`](https://jqueryvalidation.org/Validator.element/), but because ASP.NET Core uses the unobtrusive validation library, I never have access to the validator object returned by `validate()`.  So...

**TL;DR**

How do I ensure that [`valid()`](https://jqueryvalidation.org/valid/) returns the correct value in a delegated event handler when using the unobtrusive validation library?

**EDIT**

While trimming up my page's HTML to post, I got an idea for what the issue might be. My input is actually using [remote validation](https://jqueryvalidation.org/remote-method/) with the `data-val-remote` attribute. Perhaps my blur handler is just being called before the remote validation has sent a response, so the plugin thinks the input is still valid?

Comment: Did you try the `change` event, or even the `input` event ?

Comment: I just tried them.  For both events, `isValid` was actually `true` no matter what I enterred!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the issue was indeed with mixing remote validation with a blur handler.  I have since started using a more event-driven approach to validation.

```
$.validator.setDefaults({
    highlight: (element, errorClass, validClass) =>
        onValidating(element, false, errorClass, validClass),
    unhighlight: (element, errorClass, validClass) =>
        onValidating(element, true, errorClass, validClass)
});

function onValidating(element, valid, errorClass, validClass) {
    var e = new CustomEvent("validating", {
        detail: {
            valid: valid,
            errorClass: errorClass,
            validClass: validClass
        },
        bubbles: true
    });
    element.dispatchEvent(e);
}
```

The `highlight` and `unhighlight` callbacks provided to jQuery Validate's [`setDefaults()`](https://jqueryvalidation.org/jQuery.validator.setDefaults/) method each raise a synthetic `validating` event, with the `valid` property set to `false` or `true`, respectively.  These events can then be subscribed to anywhere else in the app, allowing one to move `onblur` actions to those new handlers.  In my case:

```
$('#my-container').on('validating', e => {
    var isValid = e.detail.valid;
    // Do stuff with isValid's boolean value
});
```

Because this technique uses setDefaults() and not [validate()](https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/), it can be used with ASP.NET Core's unobtrusive validation plugin!

Answer (score -1):

You are using `event.target`...

You should console.log it. I'm pretty sure that on a `click` outside the input, **but inside the `form`**, the validation is working.

But on "tab-out", which I guess means <kbd>TAB</kbd> keypress... There is no `target` attribute in the event.

So just change :

```
$(document).ready(() => {
    $('#my-container').on('blur', '.my-input-class', (event) => {
        var isValid = $(this).closest("form").valid();
        // Do stuff with isValid's boolean value
    });
});
```

Comment: Yes tab referred to <kbd>TAB</kbd> (I didn't know you could use keyboard glyphs here!).  I just tried hitting <kbd>TAB</kbd>, clicking off within the form, and clicking off outside the form, but it looks like `e.target` is always defined.  And whether I call `valid()` on the form or the input, I still get `true` for invalid values on the first blur.

Comment: Post your HTML then... **The produced HTML please!** That will make your question  ["Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and maybe I will be able to answer differently. **And if** `.valid()` is a custom named function, also post it.

Comment: While trimming up my page's HTML to post, I got an idea for what the issue might be.  My input is actually using [remote validation](https://jqueryvalidation.org/remote-method/) with the `data-val-remote` attribute.  Is it possible that my blur handler is just being called before the remote validation has sent a response, so the plugin thinks the input is still valid?

Comment: mmm... Sure, the remote validation delay to get the response may be in cause. What is `.valid()` function? Maybe there a `complete` or `success` callback which could be used...

Comment: The valid() function is just a vanilla jQuery Validate method, there is a link to it in my TL;DR above.  I've searched for validation events in the plugin before and from what I can tell there are none.  The answer to this [previous SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7247250/jquery-validation-not-waiting-for-remote-validation-to-return-true-considers-fo) describes a way to make remote validation synchronous so that calls to `valid()` work as expected, but getting it to work with ASP.NET Core's unobtrusive library may be difficult